# Kernel development

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

Is it still possible for someone to learn and start contributing to the linux kernel? looks like the contributor list seems to be dominated by paid employees from large companies. Is there still a chance that one can get their patches or bugs in the kernel or is it sort of saturated with great developers? I'm thinking on focussing on the networking subsystem. Sorry, if all this sounds too noobish, but any opinions on all this? Is it even worth it to start on this route? I plan to spend my evenings and weekends for however long it takes, assuming I will be able to make some contribution.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, this question invites a protracted discussion, which our Q&A format really isn't designed to handle.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Example: [Con Kolivas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Con_Kolivas) (of course you could also cite that in order to give arguments *against* hobbyist development). See also [this  survey](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-An-analysis-of-Linux-kernel-development-1147619.html) ([original source](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/docs/lf_linux_kernel_development_2010.pdf)):

> For the evaluation period, almost 19% of changes were reportedly contributed by unaffiliated hobbyists.

Write something interesting and relevant, head over to the mailing list (or vice versa: Ask if something is interesting at the mailing lists, then head over to development). Not even the head of development Linus Torvalds is looking at your professional status.